# Indefinite integrals with natural logs

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

I know the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\log(x)$ but I'm not sure how to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated: 
$$
\int^{3}_{2} \frac{1}{x \ln x}
$$
I think I need to substitute $x\ln x$ but from there I get stuck.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\ln|f(x)|+C$$
and in your question what's the function $f$?

Comment: I'm still confused, can you explain a bit?

Comment: We have 
$$\frac1{x\ln x}=\frac{\frac1x}{\ln x}$$ so the function $f$ is $\ln$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: You're welcome.